# In AC circuit will there be a voltage drop or current drop

Tags: power, energy

For reference purpose consider an AC voltage source of 240v 1amp and there are 3 loads connected to same 240v line one consuming 600 milliamps and another one consuming 300 milliamps.now if i add another load which consumes 200 milliamps will there be a voltage drop or current drop across the supply line. And if I connect the 600 milliamps load and 300 milliamps load (excluding the third load as I mentioned above ) to the same 240 v line will the voltage drop on the 300 milliamps load or does the it remain same as 240 v, if yes when to know if the voltage or current drops at a particular point if we keep on adding loads.i am new to electrical stuff

Comment: This is extremely unclear and I think you're not understanding what current actually is. Try to clean the question up a bit and maybe someone will be able to answer it but as it stands this is a candidate for closing as unclear what you're asking.

Comment: What exactly is a "current drop"?

Answer (score 1):

There is no such thing as an "ac voltage source of...1 amp". If you are asking about a real world power supply with a **current limit** of 1 A then you need to read the datasheet to see what happens when you exceed the recommended operating conditions.

If you want to analyze a circuit you also need to specify whether the loads are connected in series or parallel. Two loads connected in parallel will always have the same voltage. Two loads connected in series will always have the same current.

Any load connected in parallel with an **ideal** voltage source will have the same voltage, regardless of how much current it draws.

Answer (score 0):

That depends on both the source and the load.  Most likely, a 1A rated supply will work OK at 1.1A, at least under nominal conditions.  However, there will be a point where more current is unavailable while maintaining the voltage.  The voltage will droop, probably resulting in a reduction of the current, depending on the load characteristics.  (If it's resistive, any drop in voltage creates a proportional drop in current.)

Think about it like overloading a garden faucet.  You can't say whether the pressure or the flow rate changes when you pull too much water; both will reach an equilibrium.